# PHP Split table into smaller tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

Can someone help me with splitting a PHP Table into smaller collapsible tables?
I'm currently running this query to get my results from a database:

```
$querytasks = 
  "SELECT *
    FROM tasks
    INNER JOIN usercontract on usercontract.Contract = tasks.contract
    INNER JOIN users on users.ID = usercontract.UserID
    WHERE (users.Username='$Username' AND users.ID = usercontract.UserID)
    ORDER BY status, tasks.contract DESC, itemgroup DESC, item DESC";
$statement2 = $dbh->prepare($querytasks);
$statement2->execute();
$tasks = $statement2->fetchAll();
$statement2->closeCursor();
```

I'm then using a foreach loop to create a row in a table for each result from this query:

```
<table id="mytable" class="fixed_header">
  <thead class="tbl-header" style="background-color: #007BFF;">
    <tr >
      <th>Contract</th>
      <th>Task Group</th>    
      <th>Task Description</th>
      <th>Assigned By</th>
      <th>Assigned To</th>
      <th>Status</th>    
      <th>Due Date</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="tbl-content">
    <?php foreach ($tasks as $task) : ?>

    <tr style="display: none;">
      <td><?php echo $task['contract']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $task['itemgroup']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $task['item']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $task['assignedby']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $task['assignedto']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $task['status']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $task['due']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $task['id']; ?></td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-info edit"  aria-label="Settings" onclick="updateTask('<?php echo $task['contract']; ?>','<?php echo $task['itemgroup']; ?>','<?php echo $task['item']; ?>','<?php echo $task['assignedby']; ?>','<?php echo $task['assignedto']; ?>','<?php echo $task['status']; ?>','<?php echo $task['due']; ?>','<?php echo $task['id']; ?>')">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
      </a> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody> <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

My table currently looks like this:
[image: table image]

I would like it to look like this:
[image: goal]

Where "Boarding point : Chanda Nagar" would instead be "Task Group : Early Warning Notice" and "Boarding point kphb" would be "Task Group : General Communications"

I believe it can be done with JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: It can be done in php by rewriting the code to group by the task groups, it cant be done in javascript as-is as you're not grouping in the dom. What have you tried?

Comment: also your loop is wrong.. your get a /tbody tag for every row.

Comment: What do you mean by change the code to group by task groups, are you referring to the SQL query?

Comment: and thanks for spotting the mistake in the loop.

I havent tried using javascript to change this since im not experienced enough.

Comment: You can do it either in the query or sorting afterwards, If you do in query, first get the task groups as an array and then loop over them and query again for the rows. Or after the query loop over it and build an array which is grouped by the task groups e.g use the array key, then just loop over and set colspan.